# Seeing breakpoint crash in Alamofire DownloadRequest.dataResponseSerializer line + 320

Tags: swift, crash, alamofire

I'm seeing a crash in the wild for very few users but its in the Alamofire response handler.  Any help appreciated.

Feels like it might depend on a server side result but I can't pinpoint which result might be at fault... and given all of parsing is in a try catch I'm unclear why this would be crashing.

Here's the stack for what's reported as EXC_BREAKPOINT:

```
0  libswiftFoundation.dylib       0x23958417c __DataStorage.init(bytes:length:) + 280
1  Alamofire                      0x101207ed0 specialized Data.InlineSlice.init(_:) (<compiler-generated>)
2  Alamofire                      0x101207f78 specialized Data._Representation.init(_:) (<compiler-generated>)
3  Alamofire                      0x1011df918 closure #1 in static DownloadRequest.dataResponseSerializer() + 320 (ResponseSerialization.swift:320)
4  Alamofire                      0x1011df9f0 specialized thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed URLRequest?, @guaranteed NSHTTPURLResponse?, @in_guaranteed URL?, @guaranteed Error?) -> (@owned Result<Data>) (<compiler-generated>)
5  Alamofire                      0x1011dbdcc specialized closure #1 in DownloadRequest.response<A>(queue:responseSerializer:completionHandler:) + 224 (ResponseSerialization.swift:224)
6  Alamofire                      0x1011bd0a0 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () (<compiler-generated>)
7  Foundation                     0x20bcbdef8 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
8  Foundation                     0x20bbca3e0 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 72
9  Foundation                     0x20bbc98c8 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 740
10 Foundation                     0x20bcbfc7c __NSOQSchedule_f + 272
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x20ac7a1cc _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x20ac997d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x20ac70c34 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$armv81 + 404
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x20ac70314 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 592
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x20ac7c9d4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 340
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x20ac7d248 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x20ae791b4 _pthread_wqthread + 464
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x20ae7bcd4 start_wqthread + 4
```

Building main app as well as Alamofire Pods with Swift 5 targeting iOS 11.  AlamofireObjectMapper is building with Swift 4

Using the following Pods:

```
- Alamofire (4.8.2)
  - AlamofireImage (3.5.2):
    - Alamofire (~> 4.8)
  - AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator (2.4.0):
    - Alamofire (~> 4.8)
  - AlamofireNetworkActivityLogger (2.4.0):
    - Alamofire (~> 4.8)
  - AlamofireObjectMapper (5.2.0):
    - Alamofire (~> 4.7)
```

Comment: provide console output of error

Comment: I can only give you what Fabric gives me as this isn't something I can reproduce.  I don't have console output

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem. 
In my case, this happens when I use only a 'Data' structure.
console output of error is below

```
malloc: can't allocate region
*** mach_vm_map(size=920813568) failed (error code=3)
malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

'malloc: can't allocate region' is related to memory leak issue.

Comment: and you think there's a memory leak that ALWAYS crashes exactly within Alamofire?  There's mallocs happening everywhere in the app - why would it only crash here??

Comment: you use upload function that converting Data type resouce? so.. maybe it crash when huge Data type resource upload. try using an input stream